# Django Rest Framework Nested View in Viewset

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

```
class GameInviteViewSet():
    queryset = Game.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer

    @action(
        methods=['get'],
        detail=True,
    )
    def invite(self, request, **id):
        # Invite user here with endpoint /api/games/{id}/invite/{user}
```

How would I make the above endpoint?  I can make `/api/games/{id}/invite/`, but how can I add another argument after that.

Or, according to the documentation, by default it goes

```
{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}/
```

I want

```
{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}/{prefix2}/{lookup2}/{url_path2}/
```

or

```
{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}/{lookup2}/{url_path2}/
```

So that I could do things like

```
games/{id}/{invite}/{user}/
games/{id}/{kick}/{user}/
games/{id}/{players}/{user}/gamestats/
```

To register my routers, I do the following:

`games/urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^api/games', GameViewSet, 'games')
```

`api/urls.py`: 
    from games.urls import router as games

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
urlpatterns += games.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DRF Nested Routers**](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) is a module that lets you define nested resources within the Django Rest Framework.

It has over 700 GitHub stars, and is [mentioned in the official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#third-party-packages)